# Reading .rtf file with js

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have to read .rtf file and put into label or something similar.
my code:

```
<script>
    var path = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Opis));
    var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(path);
    reader.onload = function(e) 
    {
        fileDisplayArea.innerText = reader.result;
    }
</script>
```

I read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText) that method readAsText taking blob or file. Why it doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Form RTF formatting for the RichTextBox Control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204840/windows-form-rtf-formatting-for-the-richtextbox-control)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use RtfPipe package from Nuget, 
my code looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Opis(string somethingToFind)
    {
        string pathToOpis = Server.MapPath(Url.Content(@"~/Views/Home/opisy"));
        pathToOpis = pathToOpis + @"\" + somethingToFind + ".rtf";
            try 
            {
                System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(pathToOpis);
                RtfPipe.Support.RtfSource source = file.ReadToEnd();
                MyModel.Opis = Rtf.ToHtml(source);
            }
            catch
            {
                MyModel.Opis = "some communicate";
            }

            return View(MyModel); 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Where is this **rtf(UTF)** file located? Is it local or on server?
You can't read local files directly on current browsers using javascript for security reasons.

User has to choose that file.
**zin.html**

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "zin.js">
    </script>
    <input type="file">
    <button id="myBtn">Try it</button>
    <pre id="file"></pre>
</body>
```

**zin.js**

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener('load', function() {
        document.getElementById('file').innerText = this.result;
      });
      reader.readAsText(document.querySelector('input').files[0]);
    });
}, true);
```

check this link
[Filesystem API](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)

Comment: I use virtual directory in IIS.